# What is UEFI ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD in boot sequence. How can I enable dual boot options everytime I switch on my PC?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, uefi, dell, windows-10

I've recently bought a Dell inspiron with 2TB HDD. I made several partitions in it. Further, I installed Windows10 as well as Ubuntu 14.04LTS on the same drive. There are several questions around this:

1. Although I have installed both Windows 10 as well as Ubuntu on the same disk, i.e. made it dual boot. But everytime I want to switch from ubuntu to windows I have to change the boot sequence to boot from the windows or ubuntu. Is there any option which allows me to choose from windows or ubuntu when iI switch on my PC instead of following the boot sequence. How can I enable dual boot options everytime I switch on my PC?
2. What is UEFI ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD in boot sequence. I see three options in the boot sequence, 1st and 2nd being the windows and ubuntu, and 3rd one being the UEFI. What is this UEFI exactly?
3. Moreover, I want to install Kali Linux as well on the same PC. Can I triple boot my same drive which has Ubuntu as well as Windows. Moreover, can I install the Linux on other drive and make it triple boot?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? UEFI & BIOS are not really compatible, so grub will only show systems installed in same boot mode. And then you can only dual boot from UEFI/BIOS boot tab or one time boot key like f10 or f12 on many systems.  UEFI also often has a fallback/default hard drive entry. Your ST2000 looks like a 2TB drive.  to see drives: `sudo lshw -C Disk -short `

Comment: Figure out your boot modes for both OSes, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) If they don't match, you should adjust one or the other OS. EFI (or EFI 2.x, aka UEFI) is a type of firmware. BIOS is a type of firmware. The two are entirely different, but most EFIs have a BIOS emulation mode to let them boot BIOS-mode OSes. See [Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) for more on EFI's principles.

Comment: got it, first two problems have been solved. can somebody share some solution to the third query? Can I triple boot my system, installing the third OS on the same/different drive

Answer (score 0):

If you get three options the way you describe them, then you have dual-boot options enabled. If you install a third Linux, that system will be added to the GRUB menu, as an option at startup. UEFI is how the computer boots up. You can see it in your BIOS, if UEFI is enabled.

Comment: I get that, but if I want to switch from windows to ubuntu or vice-versa then I have to go to boot menu, change the boot order and then reboot. My requirement is that, I should be able to see the option to boot into windows or ubuntu whenever I switch on my PC, instead of changing the boot order everytime.

Comment: Moreover, If I install both the OS on different drives, will it still show up in my boot menu?

Comment: I don't understand why you have to change the boot order. The boot order should appear the same, everytime you reboot, provided you don't change it by editing GRUB files. Then you simply navigate through the options with the down and up arrow keys. Are you looking for something like `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`? With it you can change the boot order, but then it will remain that way, until the next time you change it.

Comment: I can't answer the second question, I have never done that. If (and if) the boot entries are pointing to the right disk, and the right partition, it should show correctly in the boot menu. (hd0,1) is disk 1, partition 1 (sda1) and likewise (hd1,3) would be disk 2, partition 3 (sdb3.)